# Разные отступы Floating Action Button(fab) в разных версиях Android

Tags: android, material-design

Здраствуйте! 
Есть така проблема: нужно разместить 2 Floating Action Buttons c привязкой к правому нижнему углу с задаваемым margin между ними. Наглядный пример - Google Maps.
Гугл привел меня к такой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205720/two-floating-action-buttons-next-to-each-other?rq=1), где описано именно то, что мне нужно. Но делая по примеру, я обнаружил, что на своем телефоне(скрин 1, android 4.2) и на другом (скрин 2, android 5.0.2) есть разбежности. Думаю, здесь нужно баловаться с dimens.xml and styles.xml для каждой версии API(а различия между x<20 & x >= 20).

Приведу код:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />
```

[image: Android 4.2] [image: Android 5.0.2]

**P.S. Как видите, разница большая. Интересует как указать margin между кнопками по вертикали? Задавал их, но не работает(наверное через anchor).**

Comment: В целом вопрос очень интересный,  потому что считаю, что такие моменты должны проглядываться разработчиками google. Вы нашли, то что они не учли, поэтому +1 Вам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Взяв за основу ответ @shwarz-andrei, я начал экспериментировать со своей задачей. Итого, у меня получилось(хотя тестировал только на двух вышесказанных девайсах).

И так, начнём.
***Для начала я обьявил константы в values/dimens.xml:***

```
<!--Floating Action Button margins-->
    <dimen name="fab_margin_top">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin_bottom">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin_right">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin_between">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin_extra_right">4dp</dimen>
```

***... в values-v21/dimens.xml соотвествено:***

```
 <dimen name="fab_margin_top">16dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="fab_margin_bottom">16dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="fab_margin_right">8dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="fab_margin_between">64dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="fab_margin_extra_right">8dp</dimen>
```

***Код разметки:***

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_margin_between"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_down"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="end" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/divider"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_extra_right"/>
```

**Результат:** всё заработало так, как мне нужно было, а именно - одинаковое отображение двух FAB на разных версиях Android(в моём случае - Android 4.2 и 5.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

CoordinatorLayout использует anchor, чем-то похоже на привязки как в RelativeLayout, попробуйте сделать кастомный разделитель, привязать (приякорить:) его к нижней fab, а второй fab2 уже к этому разделителю, вот такой пример:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#e2022068">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_down"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/divider"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

где высота divider и будет расстояние между двумя fab по вертикали.

Comment: Решил попробовать Ваш код, и вот результат. Андроид 4.2 и 5.0.1 соответственно: [Андроид 4.2](https://pp.vk.me/c630317/v630317160/197f0/fssQLio9nMw.jpg), [Андроид 5.0.1](https://scontent-ams3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlp1/v/t34.0-12/12736245_708295005979553_546494849_n.jpg?oh=3788ce4c122d4ab572b488b5398a1042&oe=56D70CD0).  Как видно, дело в больших bounds кнопок в версии 4.*

Comment: Тоесть, я не могу уменьшить отступ между двумя Float Action Button, если в preLollipop версии андроид макет рисуеться с большими оступами за счёт тени. Вот если бы как-то "наехать" безболезненно одним fab на другой без потери кликабельности, или же убрать высоту, "отведенную" под тень.

Comment: здесь тень вообще не при чем, то что происходит смещение на API15+, это из-за работы библиотеки, там видимо есть разница. получается что отступы верхний баттон учитывает а нижний нет, думаю это легко поправить я изменю код нужно отступы задать в родительском layot а не в FAB вот и всё, попробуйте заново.

Comment: Я ради этого проверил на трех реальных устр-х начиная с API15+ все работает как часы, можно настроить как вам угодно.

Comment: С отступами справа и снизу(для нижней кнопки) - проблему решило. Но вот оступ между конпками как был, так и есть у меня.  P.S. Тестирую на 4.2, а компилирую SDK API 23. Библиотеки: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'. В первом коментарии к этой ветки видно, что на андроид 4.2 мы можем выставить margin= 0, и тогда у нас будет то, что нужно(за счёт пространства, которое кнопка занимает под типо тень(ну я так вычитал)). Но проблемка в двух нопках, одна над одной.

Comment: Там можно ставить оступы больше за стандартной, тогда будет толк, но если меньше, тогда хоть 0 ставь - всё равно будет "зазор" между кнопками по вертикали приблизительно ~8-32 dp. Какую версию supportlibrary вы используете?

Comment: потому что как я уже писал, если суппорт библиотека используется то отрисовка учитывает рамзеры контейнера fab, вы можете легко это исправить квалификаторами для разных устройсвт. Вам необходимо во втором fab2 в моем примере убрать layout gravity, тогда кнопка привяжется вплотную к divider, и выставить нужную высоту, вот здесь тогда высота будет разная для разных устройств - используйте как к примеру denim в ресурсах, в lolipop 0 а в API < поставьте 25dp у меня кнопки вплотную ставятся и работает на всех устр-ах.

Answer (score 1):

Я такую задачу решил, программно задав положение кнопки для версий 5+:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        fab.setLayoutParams(getFabLayoutParams());    
}

private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getFabLayoutParams() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,fab2)
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    lp.bottomMargin = 20;
    lp.rightMargin = 20;
    return lp;
}
```

По умолчанию - margin=0 (для версий меньше 5ой отступ выставляется сам).